# Using substring length to determine how to splice returning not-a-number

Tags: javascript, substring, string-length

Im using a substring of a variable to determine how to slice a string.
The string itself is four characters long and has a number attached. i.e "doop0"/"doop1" etc. Im trying to use the strings length to determine whether or not to slice more off. Like if the string becomes "doop10" slice off the "10" and parseInt it. but I get NaN returns and I dont know why!
the code I have looks like this:

```
    var num;
    var numberCount = -1;
    var nameCount = 5;
    socket.on('Balls', function(msg)
    {
        console.log("Minus: "+parseInt(msg.Name.Length) - nameCount);
        if(msg.Name.length == nameCount)
        {
            num = parseInt(msg.Name.slice(numberCount));
        }
        if(msg.Name.Length > nameCount)
        {
            console.log("Minus: "+msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
            numberCount- (msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
            nameCount+ (msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
            num = parseInt(msg.Name.slice(numberCount));
        }
```

The initial if statement will look at the msg and slices off the relevant information.
The second if statement will check to see if the length has grown i.e. "doop9" has become "doop10" or if has gone into the 100's

```
numberCount- (msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
```

Will increase the amount cut off the string

```
nameCount+ (msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
```

Will increase the name count so it will be in the first if statement

```
num = parseInt(msg.Name.slice(numberCount));
```

Gets that instance .
Is there any reason im getting a NaN error?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the `object` looks like? By default the length property on Strings is not capitalized, so unless you created your own property, that might be the issue.

Comment: Why not just use regex to get the number? `'doop10'.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // 10 `

Comment: I spelt length wrong I used a capital aswell :(

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that you are calling `numberCount- (msg.Name.Length - nameCount);`, which isn't going to do anything, because it doesn't modify in-place. Instead, try adding an `=` after this. Also, you are trying to subtract an `integer` from a `string`:

```
console.log( ("Minus: " + parseInt(msg.Name.Length)) - nameCount );
```

Which is trying to take (for example) `"Minus: 4"`, and subtract `3` from it: `"Minus: 4" - 3`, which will result in an `NaN` error.

Fixed code:

```
var num;
var numberCount = -1;
var nameCount = 5;
socket.on('Balls', function(msg)
{
    console.log("Minus: "+(parseInt(msg.Name.Length) - nameCount));
    if(msg.Name.length == nameCount)
    {
        num = parseInt(msg.Name.slice(numberCount));
    }
    if(msg.Name.Length > nameCount)
    {
        console.log("Minus: "+(msg.Name.Length - nameCount));
        numberCount-=(msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
        nameCount+=(msg.Name.Length - nameCount);
        num = parseInt(msg.Name.slice(numberCount));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations. You are adding a number to a string and than trying to subtract a number from a string.

Your code is this:

```
console.log( ("Minus: " + parseInt(msg.Name.Length)) - nameCount );
```

When you need this

```
console.log( "Minus: " + (parseInt(msg.Name.Length)) - nameCount) );
```

There is also other issues with your code with doing addtions/subtractions, but not storing the value.